# como integro mercadopago connect PHP

Tags: php

Hola como hago para integrar mercadoconnect a mi plataforma de ventas, lo estoy desarrolando en **PHP**, y lo que mas necesito es como hago las pruebas, si me pueden asesorar en eso, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido para que sea bien recibida tu pregunta lee **[ask]** y según los consejos que se te den ahí edita la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo leer la documentacion oficial:

[Checkout básico](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/receive-payments/)

[como Probar](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/)
Basicamente para probar tienes dos opciones:

- Sandbox

  Puedes simular un flujo de pagos completo en nuestro entorno Sandbox, con las siguientes ventajas:

  Los pagos son ficticios para que hagas tranquilo todas las pruebas que quieras.
  No necesitas usar tu tarjeta de crédito real para probar el flujo de pagos.
  Podrás probar tu desarrollo completo e incluso recibir las Notificaciones de pago (IPN).
- Usuarios y tarjetas de prueba

De una manera más avanzada puedes probar también en el entorno real, utilizando usuarios de prueba. Puedes crear estos usuarios y operar con ellos en tu integración como si fueran usuarios reales.
Mas detalle de crear usuarios y tarjetas de prueba en los links:

[Crear Usuarios de Prueba](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-users/)

[Crear Tarjetas de Prueba](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/test/test-payments/)

Espero te haya sido de utilidad !!